# Switch header and footer after every page

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Hello guys i want to transform with xslt my xml file into an xsl:fo document. My issue how can i switch the header for right and left Pages (alternate) after every Page.

With my solution now I only get one Page.

I use Saxon HE and xslt 2.0

my xsl:fo File:

```css
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
 <fo:layout-master-set>
  <!-- Right Page -->
  <fo:simple-page-master  master-name="rightPage">
   <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin="20mm 0mm 20mm 0mm"/>
   <fo:region-before region-name="rightPageHeader" extent="5in"/>
  </fo:simple-page-master>
  
  <!-- Left Page -->
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="leftPage">
   <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin="20mm 0mm 20mm 0mm"/>
   <fo:region-before region-name="leftPageHeader" extent="5in"/>
  </fo:simple-page-master>
  
  <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="pages">
   <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="rightPage" odd-or-even="odd"/>
    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference odd-or-even="even" master-reference="leftPage"/>
   </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
  </fo:page-sequence-master>  
 </fo:layout-master-set>

 <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">   
  <fo:static-content flow-name="rightPageHeader">
   <fo:block>
    <fo:block text-align="left" font-weight="bold">Standard configuration</fo:block>
    <fo:block text-align="right">
     <fo:external-graphic src="headerHico.jpg" height="2.00in" width="2.00in"/>
    </fo:block>
   </fo:block>
  </fo:static-content>
  
  <fo:static-content flow-name="leftPageHeader">
   <fo:block>
    <fo:block text-align="left">
     <fo:external-graphic src="headerHico.jpg" height="2.00in" width="2.00in"/>
    </fo:block>
   </fo:block>
  </fo:static-content>
 
  <fo:flow flow-name="body">
   <fo:block>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/"/>
   </fo:block>
  </fo:flow> 
 </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your *page geometry* definition is **correct**.

However, if your *content* is short and fits in a single page, **only one page will be created** (using the `rightPage` master).

If you want to test both kind of pages, you can add this `fo:block` after the existing one:

```
        <fo:block break-before="page">
            This will be placed on another page.
        </fo:block>
```

A minor observation: at the moment, the `region-before` in both your page masters is taller than the `region-body`'s top margin (5 inches > 20mm), which could result in an **overlap** should the headers contain many lines.
I usually set a different `background-color` for every page region when I'm creating new `page-master`s, so that I can easily see their dimension, until I'm satisfied with the result.

Comment: thanks man I will test it on monday
My xml file is big if i use an another header i get 30 pages or so;)

Comment: @Franz If your content is long and many pages are created, you *should* definitely get alternating `leftPage`s and `rightPage`s; it it doesn't happen there could be something wrong with the formatting object processor you are using.

Comment: I am using oxygen and Saxon HE processor

Comment: something have to be wrong with the header because i get only one Page however big the xml file is, it stops after the first page.

With the  fo:block with break attribute i get a correct second page with the correct header but only with my text.

Comment: @Franz check if you have some *keep condition* (`keep-with-next`, `keep-with-previous`, `keep-together`) that prevents page breaks in your content; consider adding a complete, minimal FO file showing this problem (long content that is not broken into pages) to the original question, or creating a new question altogether.